# Unable to configure autofac in Web Api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am facing a weird  issue that has been making me confused during the last two days. As I have researched and tried different solution it is not solved yet.

Autofac is used as DI container. The solution contains several projects including a ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API. We are unable to configure and register Autofac in the API project, while it is working properly on web project.

I have tried several solutions such as the links below but none of them works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910758/7855321

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36063722/7855321

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277002/7855321

...

I am facing the error of "
**An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'OperationController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor"**.

The codes are provided below

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            RegisterMappers();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            //builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(OperationController).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("PSMS.Repository"))
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<PsmsDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TransactionDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).InstancePerDependency();

            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
        }
```

**OperationController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Operation")]
public class OperationController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly ITerminalsRepository _terminalsRepository;
    private readonly ITaskHeaderRepository _taskHeaderRepository;

    public OperationController(
        IUserRepository userRepository,
        ITerminalsRepository terminalsRepository,
        ITaskHeaderRepository taskHeaderRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _terminalsRepository = terminalsRepository;
        _taskHeaderRepository = taskHeaderRepository;
    }

[Authorize]
    [Route("~/api/Operation/FindTerminal")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult FindTerminal(GetTerminalInputDto inputDto)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDto.TerminalNo))
            return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable));

        var userPersonnel = _userRepository.GetPersonnelUser(inputDto.TerminalNo);

        var terminal = _terminalsRepository.SearchTerminals(new TerminalsSearchContext
        {
            Terminal = new Terminals
            {
                TerminalNo = inputDto.TerminalNo
            },
            PersonnelId = userPersonnel.PersonnelId ?? 0,
            PersonnelType = (Enumeration.PersonnelTypeEnum)userPersonnel.PersonnelTypeId,
            Take = 1,
            Skip = 0
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        var result = new GetTerminalOutputDto(terminal);
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

I again repeat, the same config works in the ASP.NET MVC project. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using OWIN, not classic Web API setup. [Per the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration):

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. **In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch.** You should not reference `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

Switch this:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

to

```cs
httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Also, not sure why you're setting the MVC dependency resolver. For Web API you don't need:

```cs
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```